# Using Chebychev's inequality to solve this problem

Tags: probability

If $X_1, X_2, \dots , X_n$ is a random sample from an unknown distribution with (unknown) mean $\mu$ and
variance $\sigma^2.$
Suppose we are willing to assume that $\sigma^2 ≤ 10.$ How large should $n$ be to ensure that
the sample mean $\bar X_n$ is within .1 of the mean $\mu$ with probability at least .95?

So..

$Var(\bar X_n) = \sigma^2/n.$

$P(|\bar X_n - \mu| ≥ 0.1) ≤ \frac{\sigma^2/n}{0.1^2} = 10000/n.$

Since it's asking for at least 0.95, do we have

$10000/n ≥ 0.95$ and
then $n = 10526$?

Was wondering if this was the correct answer.

Comment: I have proposed a revision using $TeX$ to avoid confusion between the final observation $X_n$ and the sample mean $\bar X_n.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer does not quite make sense. More properly saying your answer is $n \leq 10526$ instead of $n = 10526$. But as you can imagine, the more samples you have, the more accurate you can get. So the threshold condition should be $n \geq N$ for some $N$.

The problem arises from
$$\frac{10000}{n} \geq 0.95$$

First of all $\frac{\sigma^2}{0.1^2} = 10 \times 100 = 1000 \neq 10000$. Even if this is correct, the probability on the left hand side is not that the sample mean is **within** $0.1$ of the mean $\mu$, but that the sample mean is **not within** $0.1$ of the mean $\mu$. Instead the criterion should be
$$1 - \frac{1000}{n} \geq 0.95$$
which is
$$\frac{1000}{n} \leq 0.05$$
and therefore
$$n \geq 20000$$

Comment: Is it because the question says "(unknown) mean" then we can assume the sample mean is not within 0.1?

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your question. But you can regard this question as a procedure to estimate the mean of a random variable: by a sample mean of a large sample. What we should decide is the size of the sample such that the sample mean is a sufficiently good estimator to the mean of the random variable, that is, the sample mean lies within 0.1 of the mean of the random variable.

Comment: Oh I see. Thanks a lot!